# how do i erase a printed text in a fancy way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create make the text write and erase itself. I already found out how to make it write each character per time, but i haven't found how to make it erase itself in the same way (from the first letter to the last)

```
import time
import os
import sys
from time import sleep

txt = "wake up neo"

# writing itself (i wanted to do the same for deleting):
for x in txt:
  sys.stdout.write(x)
  sys.stdout.flush()
  sleep(0.05)

os.system("clear")
print("wake up neo")
time.sleep(3.0)

# here's where it starts to delete itself:
os.system("clear")
print("\r ake up neo")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r  ke up neo")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r   e up neo")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r     up neo")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r     up neo")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r      p neo")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r        neo")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r        neo")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r         eo")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r          o")
time.sleep(0.05)
os.system("clear")
print("\r")
os.system("clear")
```

Not only that but i wanted the text to be stationary as well. i don't want the text to retreat itself for each deleted character.

I hope i have been clear.

Comment: Do you have a question about a specific technical problem you encountered?

Comment: As long as you're using ```\r``` to go back to the start of the line, you can print spaces over the previous output, and leave a pause between each space if that's the "fancy" effect you're after.

Comment: That said, I'd get rid of the `clear`s entirely. You can just write a single `\r`, and then a space at a time between them until you've overwritten the whole string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Of course, this requires `end=''` as an additional parameter in `print`s.

Comment: @Błotosmętek, who's using `print`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the OP was :-P

Comment: Ahh, right; I was paying attention only to their initial loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, time

txt = "wake up neo"

for t in (txt, '\r' + ' ' * len(txt) + '\n'):
    for x in t:
        sys.stdout.write(x)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
    time.sleep(3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's exactly what i wanted